# Batch rename image files (replace space with hyphen)

Tags: windows

I have a folder which contains 4 sub folders and in each of these 4 folders there are more folders that contain images.

I need to replace all the spaces in the image names with hyphens e.g.

**blue magazine.jpg** would become **blue-magazine.jpg**

Is there any way I can do this using a batch file / some free software / via command prompt or any other ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `for`.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %i in ('dir /b /s *.jpg') DO move "%i %j" "%i-%j"
```

This would replace spaces with hyphens in .jpg files in the current directory and subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I do all my scripting work using linux bash. This way knowing one scripting language is enough. To have it on Windows, install [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS). Then use commands [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) with `-exec` clause and [`mv`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mv).

I install MSYS also in Windows server environments, without problems. Actually the installation process is not necessary. It runs simply after copying the files.